# Implicit conversion of C pointer warning

Tags: c, struct, types, declaration

I am using a linked list defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct {
    struct foo* next;
} foo;
```

Assuming that it has already been set up with the head pointer called `linked_list` and I want to iterate through the linked list as follows:

```c
foo* curr = linked_list;
while(curr->next) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

My compiler (Clang) throws a warning about converting from `struct foo*` to `foo*` [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

I know that I can suppress this warning by casting it, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your code doesn't define `struct foo` anywhere.

Comment: A general rule of thumb: Do not use `typedef`, as it mostly ever causes confusion.

Comment: Your sense that "use a cast" is the wrong way to fix the problem is good – keep that sensitivity.  Using casts is rarely the best way to fix a problem.  Sometimes, it _is_ necessary — casts were created for a reason.  But casts are too often applied in too many situations.  They're dangerous.  Using a cast claims "I know more than the compiler about C in this context", which is rarely the case.

Comment: The warning is legit: A struct foo* is not the same type as a pointer to foo (which is a typedef for struct { struct foo* next; }).... if you don’t care you can cast or use void* which will happily let you mix pointer-types. OR you could just use compatible pointers :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the structure `struct foo` used in this declaration

```
typedef struct {
    struct foo* next;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
} foo;
```

is never defined.

As result in this expression statement

```
curr = curr->next;
```

the left operand has the type `foo *` while the right operand has the type `struct foo *`.

Rewrite the structure definition the following way

```
typedef struct foo {
    struct foo* next;
} foo;
```